# How to change daisyUI theme in nextjs using button click?

Tags: next.js, daisyui

According to [daisyUI documentation](https://daisyui.com/docs/themes/),  we can update theme by updating value of `data-theme` variable in in `<html>` tage like this: `<html data-theme="cupcake"></html>`

By looking at nextjs documentation for [Custom Document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document), I could not figure out how to dynamically update `data-theme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can update `data-theme` variable on `<html>` tag in nextjs with the help of npm package [next-themes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-themes) like this:

```
// _app.tsx
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

const MyApp = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { ...pageProps },
}) => {
  return (
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

```
// header.tsx
import { MoonIcon, SunIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";

export default function Header() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

  return (
    <div>
      {theme === "business" ? (
        <div
          className="flex-1 lg:flex-none"
          onClick={() => setTheme("emerald")}
        >
          <SunIcon className="h-8 w-8 cursor-pointer text-green-400 sm:h-10 sm:w-10" />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div
          className="flex-1 lg:flex-none"
          onClick={() => setTheme("business")}
        >
          <MoonIcon className="h-8 w-8 cursor-pointer text-green-400 sm:h-8 sm:w-8" />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Next-themes by default changes value of `data-theme` on `<html>` tag upon execution of `setTheme('value')` function